# Constructing a binary tree from an array

Tags: c++, tree, traversal

Context: Implementation of a map using a binary tree(BinStabloMapa)

The task is as follows:

Add a new constructor to the class BinStabloMapa that receives 2 arrays of positive integers(array of keys and an array of values). Given these 2 arrays the constructor should create a binary tree under the condition that the elements of the keys array are the elements of the tree in its preorder traversal, and elements of the values array are values corresponding to keys. A value of 0 in keys array means there is no node in that spot.

I have a test example here:

```
int keys[9] = {6, 4, 3, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0};
int values[9] = {6, 4, 3, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0};
BinStabloMapa<int,int> m(keys, values, 9, 1);
cout << m[3] << " " << m[4] << " " << m[5] << " " << m[6] << " " << m[9];
```

It should output:3, 4, 5, 6, 0 - however it outputs 3, 4, 0 , 6, 0.

Here is the constructor with its helper method:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
void BinStabloMapa<Key, Value>::preOrderWithArray(BSNode<Key, Value>*& node, int* keys, int* values, const int& size, int &index){

      if(index == size) return;
      if(node == _root){
            _root = new BSNode<Key, Value>(values[index], keys[index], 0, 0, 0);
            node = _root;
        } else{
            node->_key = keys[index];
            node->_value = values[index];
        }

        node->_left = new BSNode<Key, Value>(Value(), Key(), node, 0, 0);
        node->_right = new BSNode<Key, Value>(Value(), Key(), node, 0, 0);
        index++;

        preOrderWithArray(node->_left, keys, values, size, index);
        preOrderWithArray(node->_right, keys, values, size, index);

}



//Constructor
template<typename Key, typename Value>
BinStabloMapa<Key, Value>::BinStabloMapa(int *keys, int *values, int size, int dummy){
    int index = 0;
    _root = 0;
    preOrderWithArray(_root, keys, values, size , index);
    _numOfElements = size;
}
```

I know there's been similar questions, yet I can't understand why this code shouldn't work? Perhaps it can be improved?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is something from valgrind which you may find useful:

Memory leak (BinStabloMapa.h:114)

Valgrind output:
20 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
at 0x4005B65: operator new(unsigned) (vg_replace_malloc.c:163)
at 0x4005B65: operator new(unsigned) (vg_replace_malloc.c:163)
by 0x804AE6D: BinStabloMapa::preOrderWithArray(BSNode*&, int*, int*, int const&, int&) (BinStabloMapa.h:114)
by 0x804AE6D: BinStabloMapa::preOrderWithArray(BSNode*&, int*, int*, int const&, int&) (BinStabloMapa.h:114)
by 0x804AEDE: BinStabloMapa::preOrderWithArray(BSNode*&, int*, int*, int const&, int&) (BinStabloMapa.h:117)
by 0x804AEDE: BinStabloMapa::preOrderWithArray(BSNode*&, int*, int*, int const&, int&) (BinStabloMapa.h:117)
by 0x804AEDE: BinStabloMapa::preOrderWithArray(BSNode*&, int*, int*, int const&, int&) (BinStabloMapa.h:117)
by 0x804AEDE: BinStabloMapa::preOrderWithArray(BSNode*&, int*, int*, int const&, int&) (BinStabloMapa.h:117)
by 0x804AEDE: BinStabloMapa::preOrderWithArray(BSNode*&, int*, int*, int const&, int&) (BinStabloMapa.h:117)
by 0x804AEDE: BinStabloMapa::preOrderWithArray(BSNode*&, int*, int*, int const&, int&) (BinStabloMapa.h:117)
by 0x804AF77: BinStabloMapa::BinStabloMapa(int*, int*, int, int) (BinStabloMapa.h:129)
by 0x804AF77: BinStabloMapa::BinStabloMapa(int*, int*, int, int) (BinStabloMapa.h:129)
by 0x8048BD9: main (autotest.cpp:178)
by 0x8048BD9: main (autotest.cpp:178)

At the line where it says memory leak I do node->_right equals etc.

Comment: To understand why code doesn't work, use the debugger and see where the code deviates from the plan you had in mind (or better yet, the plan you wrote on paper).

Comment: I have tried but codeblocks just keeps exiting debug mode, never happened before.